# Ember Js computed property in component fails when observing object property in service

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Have an interesting problem in Ember js.

Here below is the component `advanced-search/component.js` with two computed properties `roomType` & `room` dependent on the service `services/advanced-search` `queryObj.{roomId,roomTypeId}` object properties.

The `roomType` computed property fires and updates the template correctly when an option is selected from the template.  However, interestingly, the `room` computed property fails to fire when a room is selected from the template.  This I verified by putting a `console.log('checking room computed fired')` inside the `room` computed property.

To explore this anomaly further, I did the following:

1. I uncommented the code you see in the `init` method that sets the `rooms` array which populates the room list dropdown and commented the code in the actions hash inside the `setRoomType` action method that was initially setting the `rooms` array. After these changes, the `room` computed property fires correctly and updates the template.
2. I noticed the array returned by the `this.get('store).findAll('roomType')` resulted in the `roomType` computed property to fire correctly and update the template, so I attempted to change the call for `rooms` inside `setRoomType` from `roomType.get('rooms')` to `this.get('store')` to see if it also resulted in the `room` computed property to fire correctly but it still did **NOT** fire the `room` computed property.  So, I concluded that both the `roomType` and `room` computed properties could only fire and update the template correctly if their dropdown list arrays were set in the component's `init` method.

#### advanced-search/component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
advancedSearch: Ember.inject.service('advanced-search'),
queryObj: Ember.computed.alias('advancedSearch.queryObj'),
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // I believe because the 'roomTypes` array is set in this init method, the 'roomType' computed property fires correctly and updates the template
    this.get('store').findAll('roomtype').then((roomTypes) => {
        this.set('roomTypes', roomTypes);
    });
    // When the 'rooms' array is also initialized here, the 'room' computed property fires successfully on 'room' selection from the dropdown and updates the template
    // this.get('store').findAll('room').then((rooms) => {
    //     this.set('rooms', rooms);
    // });
},
roomTypes: [],
roomType: Ember.computed('queryObj.{roomTypeId}', function() {
    var that = this;
    return this.get('roomTypes').find(function(roomType) {
        return that.get('queryObj').roomTypeId === roomType.id;
    });
}),
rooms: [],
room: Ember.computed('queryObj.{roomId}', function() {
    console.log('checking room computed fired')
    var that = this;
    return this.get('rooms').find(function(room) {
        return that.get('queryObj').roomId === room.id;
    });
}),

actions: {
    setRoomType(roomType) {         
        this.get('advancedSearch').setRoomType(roomType);
        this.set('room', null);
        if (roomType) {
            // When rooms array initialized from here  the room computed property fails to fire on room selection from drop down
            roomType.get('rooms').then((rooms) => {
                this.set('rooms', rooms);
            });
        } else {
            this.set('rooms', null);
        }

    },
    setRoom(room) {
        this.get('advancedSearch').setRoom(room);
    }
}});
```

Here below is the service code:

#### services/advanced-search

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
queryObj: {},
setRoomType(roomType) {
    this.set('queryObj.roomTypeId', roomType.id);
},
setRoom(room) {
    this.set('queryObj.roomId', room.id);
}});
```

Here below is the component template:

#### advanced-search/template.hbs

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3>Advanced Search</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          {{#power-select placeholder="Room type" allowClear=true selected=roomType options=roomTypes onchange=(action "setRoomType") as |roomType| }} {{roomType.name}} {{/power-select}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          {{#power-select placeholder="Room No" allowClear=true selected=room options=rooms onchange=(action "setRoom") as |room| }} {{room.name}} {{/power-select}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

NB: My desire is for the 'rooms' property to be set from the action method 'setRoomType' through the 'roomType' model's relationship property called 'rooms' so that the rooms are always filtered according to the 'roomType' selected.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

#### Ember Version:

- Ember Inspector   2.0.4
- Ember 2.8.2
- Ember Data    2.9.0
- jQuery    3.1.1
- Ember Simple Auth 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set the computed properties like `this.set('room', null);` This line of code is the culprit i guess.Once you set computed properties like this then this computed property will not fire again.

What you might need is `room` computed property with get and set. refer [setting computed properties guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties)

```
test:Ember.computed('dependantKey',{
    get(key){
      return 'result';
    },
    set(key,value){
      return value;
    }
  })
```

Comment: Yeah, that stood out to me as well. You are probably just better off never using set on a computed property at all, instead mutating whatever the computed property depends on instead. This keeps things predictable

Comment: Great.  I saw it immediately you mentioned it.  I cannot believe I spent 4 hours on something seemingly so obvious.  Actually, I was setting the wrong property, the wrong value.  What I meant to set was `this.set('rooms', []);`.  Now it works perfectly as the `rooms` property is not a computed property and it is the one that sets the list for the rooms.  Thanks a bunch guys!